# How can I send the data collected from a form and send it to another api route? JQuery, Node.Js API

Tags: jquery, node.js, api

I have a html page with a simple form. This page is loaded as the '/' index of my application.

with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#auth').on('submit',function(){
        getValues();
    });
});
```

I call an external file that gets the value of the inputs and has the task to do a post request to my server on another route '/login'.

```
function getValues()
{
     var values= {};

     values.username = $("input[name='username']").val();
     values.password = $("input[name='password']").val();
     console.log(values);

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data :JSON.stringify(values),
         url: "/login",
         contentType: "application/json"
     });

 }
```

API Login route:

```
 app.get('/login', function(req, res){
          console.log("sent on request: ", req.body);
          if(req.body)
          { res.redirect('/me');}
         });
```

My problem is that the login page is not being called.
I can not see the output of the req.body on the console.

How can I send the data collected from a form and send it to another api route redirecting the api to a third route?

EDIT:

```
 var send = $.post( "/login", values, function(data) {
        console.log( "1 success", data );
  })
  .done(function() {
        console.log( "2 success", data );
  })
  .fail(function(send, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log( "send ", send, "status ", status, "Thrown ", errorThrown );

            //send returns the listed object below
            //status returns only 'error'
  });
```

That call returns fail - console.log(error);

SECOND EDIT:
That is what the fail returns:

```
Object { readyState: 0, 
       getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(),
       getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(),
       setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), 
       overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), 
       statusCode: statusCode(), 
       abort: abort(),
       state: state(), 
       always: always(), 
       catch: catch(), … }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**login.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="auth">
    username <input type="text" name="username" value="admin"> 
    password <input type="text" name="password" value="12345"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#auth').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
        var btn = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
        var btnVal = btn.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data : formdata,
            url: "/login",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                btn.prop('disabled', true).val('Loading');
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.ok ==1){
                    btn.val('Success');
                    console.log('success');
                    window.location = '/welcome'; //redirect somewhere if success
                }else{
                    btn.val('Failed');
                    console.log('failed');
                    console.log(data.msg);
                }
                setTimeout(function(){
                    btn.prop('disabled', false).val(btnVal);
                },2000);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data.responseText);
                btn.val('Error');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    btn.prop('disabled', false).val(btnVal);
                },2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express'); //npm install express
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //npm install body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var result = {'ok':0};
    if(req.body.username == 'admin' && req.body.password =='12345'){
        result.ok = 1;
    }else{
        result.msg = 'wrong username/password';
    }

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
});

app.get('/welcome', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/welcome.html'));
});

app.listen(8000);
```

**welcome.html**

```
welcome<br>
<a href="/">back to login</a>
```

after that run in cmd: `node index.js`

then open the browser: `http://localhost:8000`

> 1st question. how to catch success and error using jquery ajax?

answer: looks on login.html and find `success` and `error`

criteria:

1. if server responds with HTTP code header 200, this responds will return on `success` callback. else will return on `error`
2. sometimes, server result error but still send it as HTTP 200. for hack this one, i using `dataType: 'json'`. this means, the criteria for return on `success` callback is added. 1. has HTTP 200, 2. must be in the json format. else go to `error` callback.
3. in the index.js you will see `var result = {'ok': 0}` this is the default value for server respond as json. if user pass matched. change `result.ok = 1` if not matched, still keep result.ok=0 and give an extra argumentation (result.msg). in here i used `wrong username/password` in this case: client login.html will catch this respond to `success` callback but will trigger `failed` because result.ok=0 (not 1). And the last, if server throw an error for some reason, this reponds will never in json format (like error exception blabla line number xxxx). Everything that not in json format will catched by `error` callback in login.html. in the `error` i never use console.log(data), but console.log(data.responseText) because `data` will have so many object like in your screenshot, and the most usefull one is only data.responseText which will give human readable error message
4. the last portion is we need to change respond header from default `text/html` to `application/json` (hei client, im json not html) using `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` and then we convert `var result` from js object to json format using `res.send(JSON.stringify(result));`

> 2nd question. how to send data from `<FROM>` using jquery ajax and nodejs ?

answer: we need module `express` and `body-parser`

1. send as json (javascript object or array)

   - in login.html we need to build object/array and send it using: `data: JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: "application/json"` exactly like what you did.
   - in index.js we need to load module `express` and `body-parser` (you must install it first). and then we need to use `bodyParser.json()` to be able parse request in the json format (which client sent). To use it we simply write this code: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` then after that you can use `req.body.username` to get POST request
   - conclusion the requirement: `data: JSON.stringify()` + `contentType: "application/json"` + `app.use(bodyParser.json())`
2. send it as url-encoded

   - send as urlencoded is send request as string. we can use `serializeArray()` or `serialize()` to get everything in `<form>` tag. in your example you need to catch every input name to `var values`. how if you have 10 input? you need to catch every input name before you send it to server. So we change `data: JSON.stringify()` to `data: $('#auth').serializeArray()`
   - because request send as string. so we remove `contentType: "application/json"`
   - in `index.js` we still need `expres` and `body-parser`. the different is we use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` instead `app.use(bodyParser.json());` to parse urlencoded. But you can left both exists. because maybe you want send it as urlencoded / json.
   - conclusion the requirement: `data: $('#auth').serializeArray()` + `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

> 3rd question. how to send data to the 3rd routes

actually i dont know what you mean about this.because you need more specify the question. but maybe this example can explain that

modified of **index.js**

```
...

function test(name){
    console.log('my name is '+name);
}

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var result = {'ok':0};
    if(req.body.username == 'admin' && req.body.password =='12345'){
        result.ok = 1;
    }else{
        result.msg = 'wrong username/password';
    }

    test(req.body.username); //send to another function

    var foo = require("./other"); //include another file (other.js)
    var nameLength = foo.other(req.body.username); //run function other() from file other.js
    console.log(nameLength);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
});

...
```

**other.js**

```
function other(name) {
    console.log("console.log from other.js");
    return name.length;
}

exports.other = other;
```

Comment: I still get an error and the data.responseText shows undefined

Comment: The data is not being sent to the /login route. On the server terminal I dont see any requests being made or outputs from the console.log

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. I’m gonna try it but can only do tomorrow morning. Anyway I really appreciate! I just have one technical question about your solution. If I want to have a separate JavaScript where I get the form data and all, like I wrote on the question, would that also work or do I have to put that together on my html?

Comment: actually i miss that one (forgot). i will update after get dinner.

Comment: Don’t worry about that I can test it later. I’m just trying to check the technical possibilities and to understand what is actually happening on my code

Comment: sry if i cant explained well. cz i really bad at english -_-

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me understanding all that. I added e.preventDefault() to my script and it worked as expected.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When handling a `POST` request, use `app.post`, not `app.get`:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
```

Comment: I believe that the data is not being sent to the /login route.
I tried app.post before but did not get any results, that was why I changed to app.get. The /login is only there to get the data sent by the jquery that is called at the index page. and redirect the user to another route.

Comment: Can you add a success and error handler to the Ajax query and see what comes out of it? BTW, you can't redirect the user page from an Ajax call without further processing on the client.

Comment: Please change `.fail(function() {` for `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {` and  `console.log( "error");` for `console.log(textStatus);`.

Comment: In that case, the jqXHR will return an object

Object { readyState: 0, 
getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(),
 getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), 
overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), 
statusCode: statusCode(), 
abort: abort(),
 state: state(), 
always: always(), 
catch: catch(), … }

Comment: What about `console.log(jqXHR.statusCode)`?